# Execute command in Read-host

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell 5.1.17763.1490, I want to display a list of names **in** the Read-Host commandlet

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $webUrl -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$availableLists = Get-PNPList | select Title
$listName = Read-Host "Enter list name (e.g. Documents). Available lists are: $availableLists"
```

Currently, it prints something like this:

```
Enter list name (e.g. Documents). Available lists are:                        :
```

Yet I expect it to print:

```
Enter list name (e.g. Documents). Available lists are: Documents, Form Templates, LibOne:
```

I can return all these list names by executing `Get-PNPList | select Title`

Comment: Try with `Get-PNPList | select -Expand Title`. If the objects returned by `Get-PNPList` don't have a `ToString()` overload, then they may not have a way to be stringified.

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks, it looks better now. `Enter list name (e.g. Documents). Available lists are: appdata appfiles Composed Looks Theme Gallery User Information List Web Part Gallery: ` Do you know how can I separate all these values by comma?

Comment: Use
```$availableLists = (Get-PNPList).Title -join ', ' ```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$availableLists = (Get-PNPList).Title -join ', '
$listName = Read-Host "Enter list name (e.g. Documents). Available lists are: $availableLists"
```

did the trick.